# Session Storage lost on window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have a booking application developed using AngularJS that is building up details of the users booking through various pages. These details are stored using SessionStorage (I want to avoid LocalStorage).

When the user gets to the payment page, I generate a PayPal token using a REST call and then redirect them to PayPal.

The code I'm using for this re-direct is:

```
window.location.replace("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?useraction=commit&token=XXX&ul=0#/checkout/login");
```

When PayPal sends me back to my confirmation page the contents of SessionStorage have been cleared - but this only seems to happen on mobile devices, I can't replicate it with Chrome on desktop.

**Why does the SessionStorage get cleared?**

My understanding is that because I'm not opening a new page (I'm just re-directing) the state should be persisted. Documentation I have read says that SessionStorage is cleared when the window is shut - does this not differ from a redirect?

**Is there a way to redirect to PayPal whilst persisting SessionStorage on return?**

Comment: Can you confirm that this works with LocalStorage? (just to be sure that the problem is specific to SessionStorage) Also, is your checkout page using the same protocol than the page that redirects to Paypal? (either both HTTP or both HTTPS)

Comment: Hi Arnauld, The protocol is the same, I've just tried LocalStorage and this works fine. It's something about Session Storage on Mobile Phones.

Comment: I see. That doesn't sound very good. May I ask you what your primary motivation is for not using LocalStorage? Confidential user data that should not lie around a public computer, maybe?

Comment: Hi Arnauld, exactly - I'm storing an order number plus the users address there. This is something I want to be lost when the user closes the page.

I could use Cookies but I'm interested into why Session Storage won't let me achieve what I want.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: I would recommend to use your server as the temporary storage medium for this data and get it back on the checkout page, rather than saving it locally (whatever method is used for that). That said, it does not take anything away from the interest of your question -- which I'm unable to answer adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple test application that added an item to SessionStorage and used location.replace to go to PayPal which returned me back to another page in the application.

The result was that SessionStorage was persisted!

Turns out some code had been committed to the application which was clearing SessionStorage out, mystery solved.